# Show that if $K\subset L$ then $\sigma(K) \subset \sigma(L)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Define $\sigma(K) := \bigcap\{\mathcal{F}: \mathcal{F} $ is a $\sigma$-algebra on$ X , K\subset \mathcal{F}\}$

Show that if $K\subset L$ then $\sigma(K) \subset \sigma(L)$.

Any help how to approach this problem ?

It seems kind of trivial to me.

Comment: $\sigma(L)$ is a sigma algebra containing $K$, so...

Comment: Similar statements exist for all sorts of hull operators, e.g. taking the ideal of ring elements, taking the topological closure of some set of points, taking the algebraic closure of fields, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I agree it is a bit trivial, I would show it in these two steps: 
**Step 1:** (The interesting of the 2)

> $\mathcal S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and $K \subseteq \mathcal S$ then $\sigma(K) \subseteq \mathcal S$.

**Step 2:**

> Show that $K \subseteq \sigma(L)$

The steps have been set in spoilers if you want to solve the rest yourself.

**Solutions:**

> Step 1: Assume $P \in \sigma(K)$ then, since $P$ is in every $\sigma$-algebra that contains K, $P \in \mathcal S$. 
>  Step 2: This follows from the fact that $K \subseteq L \subseteq \sigma(L)$

Hope it helps!